# Cut the matchsticks - HackerRank Challenge - C implementation

Tags: c, arrays

The problem is as follows: 
Suppose you have some sticks of integral length. The sticks are **cut** in such a way that all of them are diminished by the length of the **smallest stick** in each iteration. You have to display the ***number of sticks cut in each line.***
The above step is repeated until there is nothing left. Example:

6

5
4
4
2
2
8

Here 6 is the number of sticks, and the rest are the lengths of the various sticks.

The sample output is:

6
4
2
1

Why? In the first operation, 2 is cut from each of the sticks. So the new lengths are

3
2
2
6

So all the sticks are cut in this iteration, and number of sticks cut is 6. And so on.

The code is as follows:

```
int i,j,size,curmin,c,k,temp,Array[1000];
scanf("%d", &size);
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d ", &Array[i]); 
  for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
         {
           for(j=0;j<size-i-1;j++)
            {
                if(Array[j]<Array[j+1])              //sorting using bubble sort
                 {
                   temp=Array[j+1];
                   Array[j+1]=Array[j];
                   Array[j]=temp;
                 }
             }
         }
         int count=0; // for counting number of elements which are zero
         for(i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
         {
             if(Array[i]==0)
                 count++; // store number in count variable

     }
 if(count==size)  // exit program if all elements of array are zero
     exit(1);

 for(j=0;j<size;j++)
 {

     c=0; //for finding number of sticks cut in each loop
     curmin=Array[0]; // for finding out minimum value in array for the running loop, assume that first element is minimum
     for(i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
     {
         if(curmin>=Array[i] && Array[i]>0) //find minimum value in the current loop, obviously it cannot be zero, hence the second condition
         {
             curmin=Array[i];
         }
     }
     for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
         if(Array[i]>=curmin)
         {
             Array[i]=Array[i]-curmin; // subtract minimum value from each element
             c++; // increase number of elements cut by one - since we need to find this quantity for each loop
         }
     }
     printf("%d\n",c); // print number of elements cut after each loop
     if(c==1) //we know that no sticks can be cut further, so break 
         break;
 }
```

This is a HackerRank challenge, and out of the 9 testcases provided, 7 work and run. 
I am literally stumped here. Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Using var names longer than one letter, and describing what they represent, would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry @MartinJames. Will edit very shortly.

Comment: You have a limit of 1000 items in your code (`a[1000]`).  Is there such a limit in the challenge?

Comment: Yes, the program has two constraints: size of the array should be between 1 and 1000, both included, and the size of the elements should be between 1 and 1000, again both included.

Comment: Perhaps you're just running out of time. Bubble sort is very slow. Instead, use one of the stdlib sorting functions, like `qsort()` for example.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I tried to use qsort(), but then the output returns all values equal to the maximum value. (ex - 8). Are there any more sorting functions in stdlib that I could use?

Comment: @SiddharthaKhanooja Using `qsort` properly would fix that problem.

Comment: There's another problem. If `size=6` and `Array[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };`, what is the output of your program?

Comment: the output is 6 6 6 6 6 6. I am guessing this is wrong. The correct output should be 6.